# Interferences coming from/out of the grid/network (electricity)

Tags: meaning, word-choice, grammar

I am trying to tell my colleagues that they need to run a device on batteries (not on charger) to rule out intereferences that could be caused by insufficient interference-shielding in their building, i.e. coming from the grid (or network - meaning the electrical grid).
How could I best phrase the sentence:

> rule out interferences coming from/out of the grid/network
>   (electricity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

". . .eliminate the possibility of interference coming from the electrical grid."

Notice that "interference" is not plural; it is a non-count noun. Also I do not use "rule out"; that phrasing refers to  after-the-fact investigations ("ruling out" one by one the possible causes of what happened) rather than to preventive measures.  And although the electrical grid is, in a sense, a "network", the common term for it (In AmE) is "grid".